# Multivariate Conditional Survival Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ be the random variables with joint distribution $F(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. How we can define conditional survival function of $X_1$ on $X_2=x_2$ and $X_3=x_3$, that is $\bar{F}(x_1\mid X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3)$? How we can decompose it in lower dimensional conditional survival functions? For example, suppose  $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the random variables with joint distribution $G(x_1,x_2)$ then conditional survival function of $X_2$ on $X_1=x_1$ may be expressed as $\bar{G}(x_2\mid X_1=x_1)=1-G(x_2\mid X_1=x_1)$. My question is that any relationship holds for general random vector $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ for $n\geq 3$ in terms of lower-dimensional conditional survival functions?

Comment: I suspect too many people have hair-triggers when the hit the "close" button and that that's what happened here. $\qquad$